Addition First Big Letter in Gregorian Chant musixgre library
It is needed to add a First Big Letter in Gregorian Chant musixgre library. I am trying to use lettrine package with parindent command. The basic code is as follow:
\documentclass[%
latin,spanish,
border={22pt 7pt 196pt -7pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}%
\usepackage{musicography}%
\usepackage{scalerel}%Escalar símbolos
\usepackage{musixtex}%
\input musixlyr%
\input musixlit%
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amssymb}% %$\shortmid$ and $\mid$
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}%
\usepackage{fontawesome5}%
\usepackage{fontspec}%
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}%
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\begin{document}%
\textcolor{red-undar}{\lettrine[lraise=0.81,lines=2]{U}{}}
\begin{music}%
\hsize=1.55\linewidth% not: \pagewidth
\nostartrule% you omitted this!
%\hsize=\linewidth%
%\scale{0.7}%
\resetlyrics%
\setlyrics{Letras}{t que-ant la-xis re-so-ná-re fi-bris Mi-ra ges-tó-rum fá-mu-li tu-ó-rum, Sol-ve po-llú-ti lá-bi-i re-á-tum,
Sanc-te Jo-án-nes. Nún-ti-us cel-so vé-ni-ens Ol-ým-po, Te pa-tri mag-num fo-re nas-ci-tú-rum, No-men et vi-t{\ae} sé-ri-em ge-rén-d{\ae} Ór-di-ne pro-mit. Il-le pro-mís-si dú-bi-us su-pér-ni,
Pér-di-dit promp-t{\ae} mó-du-los lo-qué-l{\ae}: Sed re-for-más-ti gé-ni-tus pe-rémp-t{\ae} Ór-ga-na vo-cis. Ven-tris obs-trú-so ré-cum-bans cu-bí-li Sén-se-ras Re-gem thá-la-mo ma-nén-tem: Hinc pa-rens na-ti mé-ri-tis ut-ér-que Áb-di-ta pan-dit. Sit de-cus Pa-tri, ge-ni-t\'{\ae}-que Pro-li, Et ti-bi com-par u-tri-ús-que vir-tus, Spí-ri-tus sem-per, De-us u-nus, om-ni  Tém-po-ris {\ae}-vo. Am-en.}%
\setsongraise{1}{0.15cm}%
\font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
%\parindent0mm
%\sepbarrules
\instrumentnumber{1}%
\nobarnumbers%
\setlines14%
\setclef1{3000}%
\setstaffs11%
\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianFclef
%\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianCclef%
%
\newcommand{\dsbrm}{\zcharnote{0}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (0.15,0.15);%
\node at (0,0) {};
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.27,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
%\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}}%
%
\newcommand{\sbrm}{\zcharnote{0}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (0.15,0.15);%
\node at (0,0) {};
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.27,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
%\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
%\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}}%
%
\newcommand{\ustt}[1]{\raisebox{0.2\Interligne}{\kern-1.4pt \ust {#1}\kern1.4pt}}% normal size \ust centered and put higher for notes on a line
%
\newcommand{\usttt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf\medtype \kern0.3pt\raisebox{0.1\Interligne}-\kern0.3pt}}% shorter \ust
%
\newcommand{\btt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf{\kern1.16pt \raisebox{-0.9\Interligne}{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}\kern-1.16pt}}}% vertical bar below center of note head (original distance) 
\newcommand{\ptt}[1]{\kern-4pt\pt {#1}\kern4pt}% point closer to note head (original distance is defined for larger \nq)
%
%\newcommand{\caeg}{\zcharnote{5}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%Barra Vertical
%\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.295) -- ++(0,0.15); %
%\end{tikzpicture}}}% works, but quite complicated if there is an existing symbol in amssymb
%
\newcommand{\caeg}{\charnote{d}{\kern-4.1pt$\A\textbf\shortmid$\kern4.1pt}\hbsk}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbr}{\notes\zcharnote O{\kern-1.1pt$\A\textbf\mid$\kern1.1pt}\hbsk\en}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbre}{\zcharnote O{\kern-1.6pt$\A\textbf\mid$}}% see differences in spacing
%
%\parindent10mm
\startpiece%
\A\assignlyrics{1}{Letras}%
\addspace{0.5\afterruleskip}%
\notes\zcharnote{1}{\hspace{-2.15cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Raya vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{II}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{a}\squ{a}\btt N\squ{N}\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ{b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}\squ{b}\squ{a}\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt c\squ{cded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\en%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\zalaligne% there is no \alaligne, it is a custos, for which I haven't found a symbol yet (half a \squ mirrored, with stem up)
%
\notes\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg%
\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk%
\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{aa}\btt N\squ{N}\en%
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ {b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}%
\squ{b}%\ustt b%
\squ{a}%\ust c%
\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt{c}\squ{c}%\pt c%
\squ{ded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\sk\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}%
\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\en
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}% 
\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt{a}\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{aa}\btt N\squ{Nab}\ptt b\squ{b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}%\hbsk% 
\squ{ba}\clivis{b}{N}\en%
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt{c}\squ{cded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\sk\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg%
\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{a}\squ{a}\btt N\squ{N}\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ{b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}\squ{b}\squ{a}\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt c\squ{cded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\en%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\zalaligne% there is no \alaligne, it is a custos, for which I haven't found a symbol yet (half a \squ mirrored, with stem up)
%
\notes\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg%
\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk%
\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{aa}\btt N\squ{N}\en%
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ {b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}%
\squ{b}%\ustt b%
\squ{a}%\ust c%
\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt{c}\squ{c}%\pt c%
\squ{ded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\sk\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}%
\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\en
%\zalaligne%
\zstoppiece\hsize=0.8\linewidth% not: \pagewidth
\startpiece\notes\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk\torculus{a}{b}{a}\ptt{N}\ptt{a}\podatus{N}{a}\dsbrm\en%
\zstoppiece
%\nolyr%
%\lyricsoff%
\end{music}
\centering%not working in centering the synbol
\newpgfornamentfamily{pgfhan}
\pgfornament[width = 5cm, color = red-undar]{59}
\end{document}

The current output is as follow:

The desired output is as follow:


Please don't mix different questions in a single post. And please try to minimise your code to focus on the problem you are trying to solve. This would make it easier for future users with the same problem to adapt any answer you might get to their own code.

Just an opinion: The first thing I would do as a singer who receives such music sheets is to write the “U” in pencil directly in front of the “T” again. Typesetters should really think more often about those who have to work with their results …

I don't see that you searched manuals or tried anything yourself. Instead of saying in a comment that my comments have solved your problem, you post an answer, gaining points, as if you have done any efforts. Please, tell what you have tried, before asking a question.


Lettrine "produces a dropped capital ", so don't be astonished that it starts lower than your line. You could raise it. 2. Your following lines are indented, when you use lattrine. Maybe music is treated as a kind of list, of which the manual says "\lettrine does not work within lists." You just can write a raised letter immediately before \startpiece to not have the following lines indented. I haven't yet figured out how to place the roman number above the letter.


the command: "parindent" is not working in musixtex Gregorian mode...

I wonder whether you understood my last comment well: \parindent would work in music, but probably not with \letterine. What do you think of
\raisebox{0.3\Interligne}{\color{red-undar}\Huge U}%
\startpiece%
\A\assignlyrics{1}{Letras}%
\addspace{-2.9\afterruleskip}\notes\zcharnote N{\bf II}\en\addspace{3.4\afterruleskip}%
%\addspace{0.5\afterruleskip}
\notes

and so on?

Solved (again thanks Peters):
\documentclass[%
latin,spanish,
border={5pt 7pt 201pt -7pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}%
\usepackage{musicography}%
\usepackage{scalerel}%Escalar símbolos
\usepackage{musixtex}%
\input musixlyr%
\input musixlit%
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amssymb}% %$\shortmid$ and $\mid$
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}%
\usepackage{fontawesome5}%
\usepackage{fontspec}%
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}%
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{pgfornament}
\begin{document}%
%\textcolor{red-undar}{\lettrine[lraise=0.81,lines=2]{U}{}}
\raisebox{0.3\Interligne}{\color{red-undar}\Huge U}%
\begin{music}%
\nostartrule% you omitted this!
%\hsize=\linewidth%
%\scale{0.7}%
\resetlyrics%
\setlyrics{Letras}{t que-ant la-xis re-so-ná-re fi-bris Mi-ra ges-tó-rum fá-mu-li tu-ó-rum, Sol-ve po-llú-ti lá-bi-i re-á-tum,
Sanc-te Jo-án-nes. Nún-ti-us cel-so vé-ni-ens Ol-ým-po, Te pa-tri mag-num fo-re nas-ci-tú-rum, No-men et vi-t{\ae} sé-ri-em ge-rén-d{\ae} Ór-di-ne pro-mit. Il-le pro-mís-si dú-bi-us su-pér-ni,
Pér-di-dit promp-t{\ae} mó-du-los lo-qué-l{\ae}: Sed re-for-más-ti gé-ni-tus pe-rémp-t{\ae} Ór-ga-na vo-cis. Ven-tris obs-trú-so ré-cum-bans cu-bí-li Sén-se-ras Re-gem thá-la-mo ma-nén-tem: Hinc pa-rens na-ti mé-ri-tis ut-ér-que Áb-di-ta pan-dit. Sit de-cus Pa-tri, ge-ni-t\'{\ae}-que Pro-li, Et ti-bi com-par u-tri-ús-que vir-tus, Spí-ri-tus sem-per, De-us u-nus, om-ni  Tém-po-ris {\ae}-vo. Am-en.}%
\setsongraise{1}{0.15cm}%
\font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
%\parindent0mm
%\sepbarrules
\instrumentnumber{1}%
\nobarnumbers%
\setlines14%
\setclef1{3000}%
\setstaffs11%
\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianFclef
%\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianCclef%
%
\newcommand{\dsbrm}{\zcharnote{0}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (0.15,0.15);%
\node at (0,0) {};
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.27,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
%\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}}%
%
\newcommand{\sbrm}{\zcharnote{0}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (0.15,0.15);%
\node at (0,0) {};
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.27,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
%\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
%\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}}%
%
\newcommand{\ustt}[1]{\raisebox{0.2\Interligne}{\kern-1.4pt \ust {#1}\kern1.4pt}}% normal size \ust centered and put higher for notes on a line
%
\newcommand{\usttt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf\medtype \kern0.3pt\raisebox{0.1\Interligne}-\kern0.3pt}}% shorter \ust
%
\newcommand{\btt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf{\kern1.16pt \raisebox{-0.9\Interligne}{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}\kern-1.16pt}}}% vertical bar below center of note head (original distance) 
\newcommand{\ptt}[1]{\kern-4pt\pt {#1}\kern4pt}% point closer to note head (original distance is defined for larger \nq)
%
%\newcommand{\caeg}{\zcharnote{5}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%Barra Vertical
%\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.295) -- ++(0,0.15); %
%\end{tikzpicture}}}% works, but quite complicated if there is an existing symbol in amssymb
%
\newcommand{\caeg}{\charnote{d}{\kern-4.1pt$\A\textbf\shortmid$\kern4.1pt}\hbsk}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbr}{\notes\zcharnote O{\kern-1.1pt$\A\textbf\mid$\kern1.1pt}\hbsk\en}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbre}{\zcharnote O{\kern-1.6pt$\A\textbf\mid$}}% see differences in spacing
%
%\parindent10mm
\hsize=1.53\linewidth% not: \pagewidth
\startpiece%
\A\assignlyrics{1}{Letras}%
\addspace{0.5\afterruleskip}%
\notes\zcharnote{1}{\hspace{-2.06cm}\begin{tikzpicture}%Raya vertical
\node (point) at (0,0)[text width=16mm,align=center] {\textcolor{black}{\A\textbf{II}}};
\end{tikzpicture}}%
\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{a}\squ{a}\btt N\squ{N}\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ{b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}\squ{b}\squ{a}\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt c\squ{cded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\en%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\zstoppiece\hsize=1.58\linewidth% not: \pagewidth
\startpiece
%\zalaligne% there is no \alaligne, it is a custos, for which I haven't found a symbol yet (half a \squ mirrored, with stem up)
%
\notes\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg%
\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk%
\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{aa}\btt N\squ{N}\en%
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ {b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}%
\squ{b}%\ustt b%
\squ{a}%\ust c%
\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt{c}\squ{c}%\pt c%
\squ{ded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\sk\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}%
\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\en
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}% 
\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt{a}\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{aa}\btt N\squ{Nab}\ptt b\squ{b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}%\hbsk% 
\squ{ba}\clivis{b}{N}\en%
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt{c}\squ{cded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\sk\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg%
\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{a}\squ{a}\btt N\squ{N}\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ{b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}\squ{b}\squ{a}\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt c\squ{cded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\en%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\zalaligne% there is no \alaligne, it is a custos, for which I haven't found a symbol yet (half a \squ mirrored, with stem up)
%
\notes\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg%
\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk%
\squ{N}\btt a\squ{a}\squ{c}\podatus{a}{b}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt a\squ{aa}\btt N\squ{N}\en%
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{ab}\ptt b\squ {b}\en\sbr%
\notes\zsqu{b}\groff{\quilismapes{c}{d}}%
\squ{b}%\ustt b%
\squ{a}%\ust c%
\clivis{b}{N}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt{c}\squ{c}%\pt c%
\squ{ded}\clivis{c}{a}\ptt a\squ{a}\sbrm\sk\torculus{d}{e}{d}\clivis{c}{b}%
\squ{cd}\ptt a\squ{a}\caeg\btt e\squ{ede}\podatus{c}{d}\en
%\zalaligne%
\zstoppiece\hsize=0.8\linewidth% not: \pagewidth
\startpiece\notes\squ{e}\ptt e\squ{e}\caeg\clivis{d}{c}\clivis{b}{a}\squ{Nb}\ptt a\squ{a}\dsbrm\sk\torculus{a}{b}{a}\ptt{N}\ptt{a}\podatus{N}{a}\dsbrm\en%
\zstoppiece
%\nolyr%
%\lyricsoff%
\end{music}
\centering%not working in centering the synbol
\newpgfornamentfamily{pgfhan}
\pgfornament[width = 5cm, color = red-undar]{59}
\end{document}

The solved output is as follow:


Then, I think @Peters deserves the green tick... and the bounty.

Please Peters enable the tick to assign the bounty to you. Thanks.

To ask @Peters, you should better comment under his/her answer.

@ABV I wouldn't know how to "enable the tick". If you accept my answer, the bounty will be awarded after the expiration of the time set, if you cannot grant it manually.

When you accept an answer, you give fifteen points to the corresponding user. It' nice that you rewrite the full solution for your question, but you should give the green tick to the one who found the solution, usually @Peters in your case.
